# Elasticsearch not returning result;

Tags: elasticsearch

The logix_item_view_id: ebc1003mb don't return when I use a field with a custom analyzer, only when I search with logix_item_view_id exclusively I get the correct result.

I don't get it and don't know what to do? logix_item_view_id_search should return similar codes based on ngran logic, so my search it's correct in parts but why not return the code ebc1003mb? Above it's my index settings and mapping properties

I created a index in elasticksearch with the following properties:

```
{
"items_production_20181008060000331": {
    "mappings": {
      "item": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "string_template": {
              "match": "*",
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                "fields": {
                  "analyzed": {
                    "analyzer": "searchkick_index",
                    "index": true,
                    "type": "text"
                  }
                },
                "ignore_above": 30000,
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "logix_item_view_id": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "fields": {
              "analyzed": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "searchkick_index"
              }
            },
            "ignore_above": 30000
          },
          "logix_item_view_id_search": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "velow_word_start_index"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this settings:

```
{
  "items_production_20181008060000331": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "max_ngram_diff": "49",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "items_production_20181008060000331",
        "max_shingle_diff": "4",
        "max_result_window": "3000000",
        "creation_date": "1538989200382",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "searchkick_velow_ngram": {
              "type": "edgeNGram",
              "min_gram": "3",
              "max_gram": "50"
            },
            "searchkick_edge_ngram": {
              "type": "edgeNGram",
              "min_gram": "1",
              "max_gram": "50"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "searchkick_word_start_index": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding",
                "searchkick_edge_ngram"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            },
            "velow_word_start_index": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding",
                "searchkick_velow_ngram"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          },
          "char_filter": {
            "ampersand": {
              "type": "mapping",
              "mappings": [
                "&=> and "
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "Goj0nb3JQguuPjWoE69XTg",
        "version": {
          "created": "6020399"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "readme": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1536920464303",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "TfQpl9nDRHufZYT25N4n0Q",
        "version": {
          "created": "6040099"
        },
        "provided_name": "readme"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I do this search I don't get any results of the item which should be the first:

```
GET items_production/_search?explain
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
              "multi_match" : {
                "query": "ebc1003mb", 
                "type":  "cross_fields",
                "fields": [
                  "logix_item_view_id^10",
                  "logix_item_view_id_search^9"
                ]
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what i get when I make a analyze:

```
GET items_production/_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "velow_word_start_index",
  "text" : "ebc1003mb"
}

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "ebc",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "ebc1",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "ebc10",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "ebc100",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "ebc1003",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "ebc1003m",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "ebc1003mb",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

But don't get it what I doing wrong

Comment: did you test the request analyze to see what and how it is analysed (like no more than 1 work per string or only uppercase, ...)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu I edited my question and put the _analyzed return but the return was correct for me..

Comment: I don’t see a ‘searchkick_index’ in your settings?

Comment: But you’re referring to it in your dynamic template